Which method is better to understand key drivers/feature importance in prediction?
After applying two different classifiers (EBM Classifier and Random Forest Classifier) and getting similar scores, I used InterpretML functionality to identify the most relevant features in each model.
EBM feature importance uses weighted Mean Absolute Score while Random Forest Classifier is being used with Morris Sensitivity Analysis. Even though the model performances are very much similar, they are listing different features as most relevant.
Which one should I use? Is there a method to identify the most suitable approach for each scenario?
